# Sticky Position on Filters is Not Working

Tags: filter, scroll, position, sticky

I'm trying to get The Events Calendar Pro filters to sticky position on scroll.

Site: https://thecesbible.com/ces-2022-party-list-with-events-socials-happy-hours-and-concerts-by-thecesbible/

Im using this:

```
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

A parent div has `overflow: hidden`, so the sticky positioning won't work.  [This w3c Github issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865) has more details on this limitation.

In this case, you can fix it by updating this CSS:

```
.wrapper_main, .wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to:

```
.wrapper_main, .wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
```